# Are there any problems with running same cron job that takes 2 hours to complete every 10 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have a script that takes two hours to run and I want to run it every 15 minutes as a cronjob on a cloud vm. 
I noticed that my cpu is often at 100% usage. Should I resize memory and/or number_of_cores ?

Comment: @marcin mentioned in his answer you need to resize larger. You do not want 100% CPU usage for very long, networking will start to have problems. Run one job, measure CPU, Memory and Disk usage. Multiple by 8 and pick an instance size at least that large and preferably twice larger to keep the numbers below 50% usage.

Comment: by "resize larger" do do you mean increasing available memory ?

Comment: What is your cron job doing?

Comment: I am recommending that you calculate what is required and then size the instance accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you execute your cron job, a new process will be created.

So if your job takes 120 min (2h) to complete, and you will be starting new jobs every 15 minutes, then you will be having 8 jobs running at the same time (120/15).

Thus, if the jobs are resource intensive, you will observe issues, such as 100% cpu usage.

So the question whether to up-scale or not is really dependent on the nature of these jobs. What do they do, how much cpu and memory do they take? Based on your description you are already running at 100% CPU often, thus an upgrade would be warranted in my view.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your cron, but outside of resourcing for your server/application the following issues should be considered:

- Is there overlap in data? i.e. do you retrieve a pool of data that will be processed multiple times.
- Will duplicate critical actions happen? i.e. will a customer receive an email multiple times, will a payment be processed multiple times.
- Is there a chance of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) that cause the script to exit early.
- Will there be any collisions in the processing i.e. duplicate bookings made etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increase the CPU and Memory specification of your VM instance (in GCP) due to the high CPU load of your instance. The document [1] on upgrading the machine type of your VM instance, to do this need to shutdown your VM instance and change it´s machine type.

To know about different machine types in GCP, please have the link [2].

On the other hand, you can autoscale based on the average CPU utilization if you use managed instance group (MIG) [3]. Using this policy tells the autoscaler to collect the CPU utilization of the instances in the group and determine whether it needs to scale. You set the target CPU utilization the autoscaler should maintain and the autoscaler works to maintain that level.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu-load-balancing#scaling_based_on_cpu_utilization